# How can I set a constant speed with AddForce of the rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I want to move an object with AddForce but I don't want its speed to increase dramatically, without a limit, but to move with a speed limit set by a float value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use [Vector3.ClampMagnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html?_ga=2.85788313.1262116441.1589039579-1962433970.1575418699):

```cs
rigidbody.AddForce(...);

float maxSpeed = 10;
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rigidbody.velocity, maxSpeed);
```

And don't forget to play with the force inside `FixedUpdate()` not in `Update()`

Comment: thanks for the reply. in this way influencing rigidbody.velocity. So I get into trouble with the physics, I just wish that using addforce with an input my rigidbody does not exceed the speed indicated by my float on that occasion.
Because if I use it normally I continue to send force and the speed of the rigidbody increases indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

You can use clamp to restrict your value(s);

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: and where should I apply this restriction? I don't think I can apply it to the force I use on the rigidbody.
  Isn't there a way to always send the force with the same value to the rigidbody, so that it always moves at the same speed?