# Hello I cant modify Rb.vel.mag in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I'm a newbie and I have an error I searched google and there came up results but they used to work I remember but I guess it updated anyway whenever I write this:

---

```
            m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude = m_Max_SpeedBACK;
```

---

(Yes, I didn't forget to make the float itself)
And it shows this error

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45tug.png)

It said I'm not allowed to send img but anyway I want to have this if written simply
(rb.speed = float)

Can anyone help, thanks?

---

```
  using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class my_Char_Cont : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    public float m_Thrust_Forth = 20f;
    public float m_Thrust_Behind = -20f;
    public float m_time = 10f; 
    public float m_timeNeg = -10f;
    public float m_Max_SpeedFORTH = 4f;
    public float m_Max_SpeedBACK = 2f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        bool forwardPress = Input.GetKey("w");
        bool backPress = Input.GetKey("s");
        bool leftShiftPress = Input.GetKey("left shift");
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        if (forwardPress)
        {
            m_time = m_time + Time.deltaTime;
            if (m_time >= 4)
            {
                m_time = 3.9f;
            }
            m_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * m_Thrust_Forth * m_time);
        }
        else
        {
            m_time = 0;

        }
        if (backPress)
        {
            m_timeNeg = m_timeNeg + Time.deltaTime;
            if (m_timeNeg >= 4)
            {
                m_timeNeg = 3.9f;
            }
            m_Rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * m_Thrust_Behind * m_timeNeg);

            if (m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude >= m_Max_SpeedBACK)
            {
                m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude = m_Max_SpeedBACK;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            m_timeNeg = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, when you do `m_Rigidbody.velocity` you are getting a copy of `velocity`, because `velocity` is a `Vector3`, which is a struct. So any modification you could do to members of `m_Rigidbody.velocity` would only affect the copy, not anything about `m_Rigidbody`. Second, the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) for Vector3 tells you that magnitude is a readonly value.

Comment: You can skip the `if` and use [`m_Rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(m_Rigidbody.velocity, m_Max_SpeedBACK);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html). But your logic is a little wrong because what if the player is going very fast forward then they start pressing back? Their speed will decrease to `m_Max_SpeedBack` immediately, but wouldnt it be more appropriate for it to decrease over time to that speed? Think carefully about the behavior you want from this code, and then add a description of that intended behavior to the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set a constant speed with AddForce of the rigidbody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699345/how-can-i-set-a-constant-speed-with-addforce-of-the-rigidbody)

Comment: No, it doesnt and Ty for responding

Comment: I also have a problem addforce used to work evenwhen not pressed, like:
When you press W u go faster faster and when u dont it goes slower slower not just stop, how can I do it.

Comment: Nevermind ty anyway ill Try to do it myself with time --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity can be read, but not written like that. As @Ruzihm already explained.

If you want to limit the velocity while keeping the direction, do this:

```
if (m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude >= m_Max_SpeedBACK)
{
    m_Rigidbody.velocity = m_Rigidbody.velocity.normalized * m_Max_SpeedBACK;
}
```

`normalized` returns the vector, normalized so that the length (magnitude) is 1. But to clarify: it is not "(1,1,1)" - the direction stays. Example: (0.802, 0.267, 0.534) has a magnitude of 1.

Therefore, you can assign the velocity to a value, that equals the normalized velocity * your max allowed magnitude.

Comment: `m_Rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(m_Rigidbody.velocity, m_Max_SpeedBack);` also works, and the `if` can be omitted. Still, I don't think this is actually the outcome the asker wants as I explained in the comment in the question.

Comment: ty, I also have a question how to accept answer in stackoverflow

Comment: @DamirShabayev https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359